# Java Quartz 2.2.1 - Schedule

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Hi the following code triggers every 60 seconds.

How can I change it so that it will trigger once a day at 4am forever.

I am using Quartz 2.2.1 using Tomcat 7.0.53

`Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder`
`.newTrigger()`
`.withIdentity("TestTrigger", "group1")`
`.withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(interval_seconds).repeatForever())`
`.build();`

I looked at the documentation exmaples but keep getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use startAt(Date triggerStartTime) method with your desired time (4am), and then repeat it forever every 24 hours

```
     Trigger trigger = newTrigger() 
         .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
             .withIntervalInHours(24)
             .repeatForever())
         .startAt(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mmaaa").parse("24/01/2015 04:00AM"))
         .build();
```

Comment: Can you show me a snippet of startAt()?   I keep getting errors using it.  The parameter for startAt() is a Date object. So how can I get the time only? If I pass in Date 1/7/2014 4:00am, then how does it know to run it for the next day at 4am?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Cron-based Trigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/examples/Example3):

```java
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger() 
   .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0 4am * * ?"))
   .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want an easier way to create the date then use [DateBuilder](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/DateBuilder.html) to create a date with the parameters you want. dateOf( or todayAt) should work.

Something like:

`.startAt(DateBuilder.dateOf(4, 0, 0))`

Comment: I get an undefined dateAt(4, 0, 0) when I tried your suggestion.

Comment: I've seen that I wrote dateAt() instead of dateOf(). It should not compile with dateAt(), I would expect. I edited the response with dateOf(), I hope that works.